# Table with fixed height

Tags: tables

I'm trying to replicate this document in Latex but I can't achieve the following:

1. The header is shaded
2. The height of the formulas are very small and intersect with the formulas, I would like to put a fixed height for my entire table.
3. Vertical and horizontal centering.

Any help please?

[image]

Input:

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx,colortbl}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm,rmargin=3.0cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{image.png}}
\chead{{\bf\scshape\large Exercises}\vspace{0.3cm}}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt} 
\noindent
Course: \textsc{Analytical mathematics 5}
\begin{center}
TABLA DE TRANSFORMADA DE LAPLACE
\end{center}

\vspace{0.25cm}

\hrule\hrule

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
         &   $f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s)]$    & $F(s)=\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt$\\
    \hline
        $1$ &   $af(t)+g(t)$  &   $aF(s)+bG(s)$\\
    \hline
        $2$ &   $1$ &   $\dfrac{1}{s}$\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please don't create a heading for your table with `center` and then hope your `table` somewhere sensible. If LaTeX can't put your table there, it will float away leaving your heading behind. Change the format of captions if you want something fancier, but put `\caption{}` inside `table`.

Comment: Your code won't compile. Please fix the error.

Comment: I think something like `align` might work better for this kind of case. Then you can get the equations aligned properly.

Comment: The minimum separation between rows is set by the macro `\arraystretch` (default is 1).  `\def\arraystretch{1.4}` should be adequate, and 2 is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts,xcolor}

\NewTblrTheme{CaptionWithoutTable}{%
     \DeclareTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}{}
     \DeclareTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{}
     \DeclareTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}
}

\begin{document} 


\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{talltblr}[theme=CaptionWithoutTable,
    caption = {TABLA DE TRANSFORMADA DE LAPLACE},
    label={tab:my_table}
    ]{
    colspec = {c *{2}{X[c,m]}},
    columns = {mode=math},
    rows = {3em, m, rowsep=2pt}, %<-- change row height from 3em to anything as required
    row{1}={gray8},
    rowhead={1},
    hlines={solid},
    vlines={solid}
    }
         &   f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s)]    & F(s)=\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
        1 &   af(t)+g(t)  &   aF(s)+bG(s)\\
        2 &   1 &   \dfrac{1}{s}\\
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Update packages as required.

You can use `longtblr` instead of `talltblr` if you have a very long table that spans over multiple pages. In such a case, delete the `\begin{table}[h]` and `\end{table}` and replace `talltblr` with `longtblr`.

The Output is:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Focused just on table ...

What you after is simple to get by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[hmargin=3.0cm,vmargin={2.0cm,4.5cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}  %not used in this MWE
%\usepackage{tikz}      %loaded by tcolorbox
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}   % not used in this MWE

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-duck}}
%\chead{{\bf\scshape\large Exercises}\vspace{0.3cm}}


\begin{document}
%\thispagestyle{fancy}
%\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}
%\noindent
%Course: \textsc{Analytical mathematics 5}
\begin{center}
TABLA DE TRANSFORMADA DE LAPLACE
\end{center}

\hrule\hrule

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {c *{2}{X[c, mode=dmath]}},
                 row{1}  = {bg=gray8, rowsep=5pt},
                 row{2-Z} = {12mm,      % set rows height
                             rowsep=0pt}
                 }
    &   f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s)]    
        & F(s)=\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt  \\
1   &   af(t)+g(t)  
        &   aF(s)+bG(s)     \\
2   & 1 
        &   \dfrac{1}{s}    \\
3   &   &                   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This works if your table can be fit into one page. If it is longer, than you should remove `table` and instead of `tblr` use `longtblr`:

```
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     
    label=none  
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {c *{2}{X[c, mode=dmath]}},
                  row{1}  = {bg=gray8, rowsep=5pt},
                  row{2-Z}= {12mm,      % set rows height
                              rowsep=0pt},
                  rowhead = 1
                 }
```